# WPF TwoWay Binding some elements to ObservableCollection

Tags: wpf, binding, observablecollection, two-way-binding

I need bind some ComboBoxes to one ObservableCollection.
I have this `ListView`.

```
<ListView x:Name="lwCoefTables" Grid.Column="1" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource CollectionCoefContainers}}">
<ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <ComboBox x:Name="cmbCoefTableTypes" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource CollectionCoefLinksTable}}"  
                SelectedItem="{Binding CoefLinksTableType, Mode=TwoWay}" Grid.Column="1" VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="180" DisplayMemberPath="Name">
        </ComboBox>
    </DataTemplate>
</ListView.ItemTemplate>
```

I want bind my collection to all ComboBoxes and save selected items for each ComboBox.
If I fill one collection and bind it to all comboboxes in TwoWay mode I get this:

[Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Huatg.jpg)

I think I need helper class that will contain some similar collections. How to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I assume the `CoefLinksTableType` property is on the items inside `CollectionCoefContainers`?

In which case this should work, **unless** you have the same instance repeated inside `CollectionCoefContainers`.

e.g.

Something like this would behave as you describe.

```
var vm = new VM();
CollectionCoefContainers.Add(vm);
CollectionCoefContainers.Add(vm);
CollectionCoefContainers.Add(vm);
CollectionCoefContainers.Add(vm);
```

The solution would be

```
CollectionCoefContainers.Add(new VM());
CollectionCoefContainers.Add(new VM());
CollectionCoefContainers.Add(new VM());
CollectionCoefContainers.Add(new VM());
```

It might be useful to have you definitions of `CollectionCoefContainers` and `CollectionCoefLinksTable`